# Nuxt.js head function not working in Article

Tags: vue.js, vuex, head, nuxt.js

I am trying to add some Open Graph tags to each Article of my blog that is hosted in Wordpress.
This code is working when I run "npm run dev", but when I run "npm run generate && firebase deploy" is not doing the same.

This is the code that I am using:

```
head() {
return {
  title: 'This',
  meta: [

    {
      hid: `og:description`,
      name: 'og:description',
      content: 'title'
    },
    {
      hid: `og:title`,
      name: 'og:title',
      content: 'title'
    }
  ]
}
```

In my nuxt.config.js I have configured the following in the head

```
head() {
 return { 
  title: 'That',
  meta: [
  {
    hid: `og:description`,
    name: 'og:description',
    content: '3'
  },
  {
    hid: `og:title`,
    name: 'og:title',
    content: '4'
  }
]
}
```

In the article, the title that is showing is "This" but, the meta is showing the content in nuxt.config.js ("3","4") instead of ("title", "title")

What I would like to obtain is the meta tag of the article one in the  with the SSR.

Comment: Maybe [this github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2065#issuecomment-343341179) can help

Comment: @ljubadr I can't find something like that in my code.
In .nuxt/components I have:
-no-ssr.js
-nuxt-child.js
-nuxt-error.vue
-nuxt-link.js
-nuxt-loading.vue
-nuxt.js

The only one that has a v-if is nuxt-error.vue

Answer (score 1):

My problem was using `spa` (single page application) mode instead of `universal`.

My working settings in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  mode: 'universal', // changed from mode: 'spa'
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I spend 3 days on it, tried all previous nuxt versions and alternative seo modules, not helped. This is not coming from nuxt, if you started already working on seo optimisations for your nuxt project, that means that you might have many `<client-only>`, so please find all of them and check if you have `<nuxt />` inside.

I suggest check `<nuxt />` in your template files and put `<client-only>` not to entire template, just to necessary component.

This problem is not related to `ssr: true` or `mode: 'universal'`, there is really only 1 reason is `<nuxt />` inside `<client-only><nuxt /></client-only>`

Fix it and have fun with nuxt!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the [nuxt-seo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-seo) package. It adds full support for setting the most common social media tags, including auto generating canonical tags for each of your articles/pages.

You can [checkout the docs](https://nuxt-seo.frostbutter.com) site, which has a full [nuxt blog example](https://nuxt-seo.frostbutter.com/examples/blog/).

After installing the `nuxt-seo` package in your project, add it to your `nuxt-config.js` file:

```
{
  modules: [
    'nuxt-seo'
  ],
  seo: {
    // Module Options
  }
}
```

Then on each article/page, you can set the page specific title, description, and pretty much any other meta tag:

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    head({ $seo }) {
      return $seo({
        title: 'Home Page',
        description: 'Hello World Page',
        keywords: 'hello, world, home',
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

PS: I am the maintainer of the `nuxt-seo` package.