# Nuxt.js head() inside error layout not working when using in fetch() hook at SSR

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

When we throw Nuxt error function in new `fetch()` hook with `this.$nuxt.error()` syntax, the title of error page which is `not found` is not applied in browser when using `SSR` (e.g: refreshing index page) and the title is empty (or its the same as defined in `nuxt.config.js`).
But it works when on client side (e.g: switching between routes)

**/layouts/error.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>404 not found!</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: "not found",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**/pages/index.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  fetch() {
    this.$nuxt.error({
      statusCode: 404,
      message: "Page not found",
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Is it a bug or I miss something?

[Codesandbox sample project link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-kapitsa-0et7no)

Nuxt.js version: 2.15.8

Comment: Check my answer here, this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/77209969/9803005